# x86 assembler program with constants

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to write a procedure in assembler, that calculates the value of a polynomial.
I have two files:

- C source file
- ASM source file

#### C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double func(double,double);

int main()
{ 
  double x=3;
  double y=2;
  printf("%f\n",func(x,y) );
  return 0;
}
```

#### ASM file:

.386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h

```
.DATA
var DW 27

.code

func PROC a:QWORD, b:QWORD
  finit
  fld b
  fld b
  fmul
  fld b
  fmul
  fld a
  fld a
  fmul
  fld a
  fmul
  mov ax, [var]
  push ax
  fmul
  fdiv
  fwait
  RET
func ENDP

end
```

What I want to achieve at this stage is value of (b^3) / (27 * a^3).
Probably mov and push are problem's cause.

As a result I get `-1.#IND00`

I am on Windows, and using Visual Studio 2012 compiler.
For compilation I use VS2012 command line, and a following bat file:

```
del *.obj
cl -c poly.c
ml -c poly.asm
cl poly.obj poly.obj
```

#### ALSO:

Is there any way to create a procedure with more than 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load an integer onto the FPU stack you can use `fild` command. Take also a look for the `fimul` command, with aid of this you can use a integer constant directly for multiplication.

Please take care about the stack in your implementation. One way to do simply would be

```
...
fld    qword ptr [b]  
fmul   qword ptr [b]  
fmul   qword ptr [b]  
fild   dword ptr [var]  
fmul   qword ptr [a]  
fmul   qword ptr [a]  
fmul   qword ptr [a]  
fdivp  st(1),st  
...
```

After the code is done the result will be in `st(0)`.

Comment: The thing is, this is my university homework, and I should do it as shown in my first post. So it's almost 1:1 implementation of Reverse Polish Notation. I will also try your approach, to compare speeed.

Comment: Yes, you can also do it with minimized access to the RAM. But take care that you you handle the stack in the correct way. Please try to understand also the FPU commands which end with **p**.